# Merging JSON in Python, alternate to eval()?

Tags: python, json, eval

Suppose I'm dealing with the following two (or more) JSON strings from a dictionary:

> JSONdict['context'] = '{"Context":"{context}","PID":"{PID}"}'
>
> JSONdict['RDFchildren'] = '{"results":[ {"object" :
>   "info:fedora/book:fullbook"} ,{"object" :
>   "info:fedora/book:images"} ,{"object" :
>   "info:fedora/book:HTML"} ,{"object" :
>   "info:fedora/book:altoXML"} ,{"object" :
>   "info:fedora/book:thumbs"} ,{"object" :
>   "info:fedora/book:originals"} ]}'

I would like to create a merged JSON string, with "context" and "query" as root level keys.  Something like this:

> {"context": {"PID": "wayne:campbellamericansalvage", "Context":
>   "object_page"}, "RDFchildren": {"results": [{"object":
>   "info:fedora/book:fullbook"}, {"object":
>   "info:fedora/book:images"}, {"object":
>   "info:fedora/book:HTML"}, {"object":
>   "info:fedora/book:altoXML"}, {"object":
>   "info:fedora/book:thumbs"}, {"object":
>   "info:fedora/book:originals"}]}}

The following works, but I'd like to avoid using `eval()` if possible.

```
    # using eval
    JSONevaluated = {}
    for each in JSONdict:
        JSONevaluated[each] = eval(JSONdict[each])
    JSONpackage = json.dumps(JSONevaluated)
```

Also got this way working, but feels hackish and I'm afraid encoding and escaping will become problematic as more realistic metadata comes through:

```
    #iterate through dictionary, unpack strings and concatenate
    concatList = []
    for key in JSONdict:        
        tempstring = JSONdict[key][1:-1] #removes brackets
        concatList.append(tempstring)           

    JSONpackage = ",".join(concatList) #comma delimits
    JSONpackage = "{"+JSONpackage+"}" #adds brackets for well-formed JSON
```

Any thoughts? advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json.loads()` instead of `eval()` in your first example.